# VBA changes my variable content

Tags: excel, vba, date

i have this value inserted in a cell "02-01-2013"

```
  Range("C2").Offset(aPos, 0).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy;@"
  Range("C2").Offset(aPos, 0).Value = forma(t1, 2, t2)
  MsgBox forma(t1, 2, t2)
```

which the MsgBox command there displays correctly, so the string is arriving correctly to the code, cause the msgbox displays it ok, however when the second line here does it's job it records it as "01-02-2013", note the day/month inversion, i've tried everything and can't figure out why this happens, i even added the 1st line to force format before receiving the data, and still no luck. All input fields are formated correctly in dd/mm/yy.

I need this so I can make a sort, and as it is, it kills me.

Comment: What is the data type and value returned from `forma()` ?

Comment: it is declated like this Dim `forma(1 To 20, 1 To 3, 1 To 40) As String`. I have used msgbox to see the content from the several steps, and in all of them it displays correctly, just on this final step it changes, and even this last step, displays correctly on the msgbox but gets stored on the range with mm/dd/aa instead of dd/mm/aa

Comment: ...and the value returned in your particular example?

Comment: i'm not understanding your question, sorry. What do you need me to tell you?

Comment: user has input "02-01-2013", cell formated as date type dd/mm/aa, that value is copied to another cell with same formats, then copied from that to another with same formats, then insert into forma(), and it arrives there in the same way as entered by the user. when i try to send it from forma() to another sheet, i see it with msgbox correctly however it gets writen in the cell with reversed mm/dd

Comment: Sorry I missed that you had the value "02-01-2013" at the top of your post. I think this issue is likely to be related to the usual issues with "auto" date recognition in Excel: the exact behaviour often depends on what your local settings are, and "ambiguous" strings like your example (where it's difficult to be sure exactly which part represents the month and which the day) can be a problem. In this case Excel is guessing wrongly...  This doesn't happen in the Msgbox because Msgbox doesn't try to "interpret" the date.

Comment: how do i make it stop guessing? forma(t1, 2, t2) has the value "02-01-2013" that i want to pass to Range("C2") as a date as it is, so i can use a filter to arrange dates by most recent to oldest.

Comment: Not sure why you have the `;@` at the end of the format string - that just means that the date format won't affect negative dates (try "02/01/1813" for example - the 4-digit year doesn't get truncated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When placing a string value into a date-formatted cell you're asking Excel to convert that value to an actual date. How it does that can depend on your local settings and on the actual value...

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print CDate("02-01-2013") '2/1/2013
    Debug.Print CDate("20-01-2013") '1/20/2013
    Debug.Print CDate("02-22-2013") '2/22/2013
End Sub
```

If you want more control and you know your strings are in a specific format:

```
Dim tmp As String, arr, dt As Date
tmp = "02-01-2013" 'forma(t1, 2, t2)
arr = Split(tmp, "-")
dt = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
Debug.Print dt
```

Comment: thanks mate, your help solved my problem, i just had to add a catcher for nullstrings, but your concept was spot on, thanks!